# Firebase's sorting locale

Tags: javascript, sorting, firebase, localization

I created a javascript version on the sorting algorithm according to [Firebase's sorting doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#data-order) because i need to sort data in "DESC" direction in a multilanguage application. I used localeCompare() to sort strings, which is subject to the "locale" parameter and a number of sorting lexical options. Is Firebase sensible to them too, so i can pass locale or other options and consequently change the orderBy* methods behavior? How can i manage it? I can't find any reference about in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase stores strings as Unicode and sorts them as JavaScript strings. There is no way to pass in a locale. If you need something like that, you'll have to use Firebase to do the basic filtering and resort the data on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Google Cloud Functions and Firebase](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/functions-and-firebase) and do some custom designed server side sorting could be a solution.